# Should tags only reflect content in the original question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I edited this question on [Network naming in Arch Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67577/network-naming-on-arch-linux) and, as the original tags did not fully describe the range of issues at play, I included a couple more, most notably [systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd) and [udev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/udev): both of which are essential to the Arch networking stack.

Another user removed these tags and left a comment reproving me for adding them:

> please, don't add tags focusing on the kind of answer it will gather, but in the question itself.

Putting aside for the moment the applicability, or otherwise, of these tags for this question, the more general principle that this approach suggests is that the choice of tags should be circumscribed by the questioner's ignorance.

So, if someone doesn't know that the X server is running their display and they have a question about logging in to a black screen but they don't include [xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xorg), then it shouldn't be added?

By adding additional tags I haven't tampered with the questioner's original intent (or, indeed with the question itself), but added to the *relevant* metadata attached to the question.

To clarify: should tags only be added that are already explicitly included in the question. And, if not, how much discretion do we have to include additional tags that provide relevant context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main function of tags on the site is to allow experts to follow tags that they're able to answer questions about. (They additionally can be used for several other things, like searching, but fulltext and Google do a better job of searching.)

Given, this isn't so important on our fairly small site; it was functionality developed for much larger sites, like Stack Overflow.

So, to determine if a question should be tagged [systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd) you'd ask yourself, "is this question something that is within the unique expertise of a systemd expert?" The person asking the question takes the initial stab at this, but its ultimately up to the rest of the community how questions are tagged.

Trivial example: if a person asks about getting a script to run every 30 minutes, its appropriate to retag to include [cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cron) even though the OP has obviously never heard of cron.

Comment: I agree: I am wary of relying on the questioner's understanding of thier issue as opposed to the knowledge and expertise of the people that frequent the site.

Comment: @jasonwryan I think the bulk of the edits being done by Gilles are in retagging category so if you're confident that the tagging is appropriate then do it. I would educate the user that criticized this and direct them to the chat room if they're still not sure of your actions.

Comment: @slm I was sort of avoiding chat with this question as I wanted to make sure this was the consensus approach and that it was documented here.

Comment: Your example is biased towards the solution of the problem. I could perfectly run a script every 30 minutes without the use of cron. Is cron a good tool for the task? Yes, but that doesn't mean there aren't other alternatives.

Comment: @Braiam `cron` is _the_ way to do this, therefore adding that tag will bring in the relevant set of experts so the tag is appropriate.

Comment: @terdon and if I have a system that doesn't have cron? Will you force me to use cron then?

Comment: @Braiam *Yes. Absolutely. Under penalty of the comfy chair.* Serious answer: That's not what the example is. If the question were about how to do this on some system which can't or doesn't run cron, then the question would say that and I'd not tag it cron, because then it's not relevant to a cron expert.

Comment: Also, stop thinking of tags as exclusive. There are many questions tagged `sed` and `perl` and `awk`, the answers tend to use one or more of these tools. Nobody is saying that if it's tagged `perl` you _must_ use `perl`, that's the whole point of having multiple tags. So, you could tag the 30 minute questions with both `cron` and `anacron` for example, you're not forcing the OP to do anything.

Comment: @Braiam Try and manage your networking on Arch *without* udev and systemd and then talk to me about bias... Really, as I have said repeatedly, both udev and systemd are a prerequisite for networking on Arch, therefore the tags are warranted.

Comment: @jasonwryan so, following the logic, all questions that has arch and networking should mandatory have udev and systemd?

Answer (score -2):

Ok, let act like [rational people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_choice_theory#Definition_and_scope) and compare the benefits/costs of adding the tags the way you are doing:

1. I won't argue the fact that udev/systemd is relevant for the context of the question. But, I would argue that you shouldn't just narrow down the topic to just that?

   You can see [Alex answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67588/41104) which doesn't do mention of systemd nor udev, and was able to provide an answer. If the tagging was done in the start and he was ignoring either udev or systemd tag, conscientiously or inconscientiously, he wouldn't be able to share the knowledge he has. This would be prejudicial for SE which objective is sharing knowledge.
2. Is in our hands explain OP showing the world parting from **his point of view**. It doesn't matter how good you write an answer if OP himself wouldn't be able to understand how to arrive to the conclusions you have made, and is a fatal mistake presume OP's has other knowledge related to the question he's about to ask. If you don't take into account this, your answer will be rather pointless for OP and any answerer that write a suboptimal answer but it clarifies the OP doubt would be more beneficial.
3. Remember that tags is the answer to "is my question about ... ?". OP doesn't even know what udev is, nor understand systemd. The scope of his question is within the realm of "Arch Linux" with the subset of "networking" and the "ifupdown" scripts. Any answer that doesn't take into account this and guides OP to the real causes of his issues will be undeniably a bad answer for the OP.
4. The marginal gains of including more tags is infinitesimally less that the marginal costs of narrowing down the topic. If I could perfectly offer a valid answer without involving udev/systemd and don't do that because the udev or systemd tags or worse, someone looking for the same information but knows what is udev/systemd and is looking for an answer that doesn't involve either, will evade that question because it will interpret that all answers will to some extent touch the topic of udev/systemd which he's not looking for. This would produce a possible duplicated to the same question which could be avoided in the first place with a correct tagging.
5. More tags means more people might view the question, yes, but it also means that if you narrow it down too much, is more likely people will not look at the question. Is a double-edged sword. That I know enough about a topic, doesn't mean that I will know about all the possibles branch of the topic.
6. At the end of the day, you didn't need systemd nor udev tags to find the question, which means that is very likely that the tagging was done perfectly fine.
7. Is true that you can use as many tags as you like, but keep them **pertinent/relevant to the question asked**. This goes both ways: that I want to install something from source and I incidentally used firefox to download it doesn't mean that the question needs the firefox tag; that incidentally the question is related to udev/systemd but isn't included in the body of the question nor interactions with OP makes you think he has knowledge about it doesn't meant that you should tag it with udev/systemd.

Relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59334/213575

Comment: 1) Alex's answer also involves udev, he just doesn't realize 2) Seems completely irrelevant, of course answers should be clear, that doesn't mean that we shouldn't retag the question with the relevant tags 3) Again you're talking about answers in any case, an OP's ignorance is not a good reason to not retag correctly 4) Not marginal and adding more tags doesn't narrow things down, on the contrary, removing tags does. 5) seems to be the same as 4 and is not true since more tags make a question more general.

Comment: 6) Come on! Because one expert found it despite its lacking the relevant tags means that everyone will? 7) The tags that Jason added _were_ pertinent and relevant to the question. The naming scheme of NIC cards is handled by systemd/udev therefore those tags are relevant and should be included. As I said, the OP's ignorance is no reason to allow incomplete tagging.

Comment: @terdon Sorry, but that's not the case http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1024/213575

Comment: @terdon more on the topic http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59334/213575

Comment: I don't know which of my points you are referring to but none of them seem in any way relevant to that link which is talking about tagging answers. Jason's retag was not based on his answer  but on the question itself. In any case, even retagging based on the answers is a good thing. If the OP had tagged as `sed` and then accepted a `perl` answer and the post also has an upvoted `awk` solution, both `perl` and `awk` should be added to the question's tags since that will help future visitors find it and will correctly categorize the post.

Comment: OK, this one is a little bit more relevant. Again though 1) the retagging here was not based on the answer at all, it was based on the question 2) I disagree with that link. On this site we have tag-dependent syntax highlighting for example. This means that people often retag to add the relevant language tag and activate the coloring. Also, if a question can be answered using many tools and the OP has only mentioned one, it is good to bring the other tags because that way experts in the other tools will notice the question.

Comment: @terdon the point made on the post is that content is indexed along with answers and questions. Even if you don't tag it as "udev" or "systemd" people will find them because the answers contains the keywords.

Comment: No they won't. Why do you insist on this? One of the main uses of tags is to "favorite" them so questions tagged with them are highlighted. If the tag is not there this will not happen, so experts will not find the question as easily.

Comment: @terdon but it **already has an answer**. The one doing the retaggin was after he answered the question.

Comment: Huh? What does? The OP? So what? How is that relevant to anything? Are you saying that because it was answered therefore it was "findable"? That's absurd! It's like saying that because you got heads when tossing a coin once, you will always get heads with every coin toss. The point is to make it _easy_ for experts to find questions, that someone found a Q even without the right tags is not an argument against them.

Comment: @terdon it had the *right tags* the very same moment it was asked. Why are you trying to edit something when the edit adds no value whatsoever?

Comment: Because they do Braiam. That's our entire point. The question _was_ actually about systemd/udev since that is what controls the naming of the cards. The OP did not know this but perhaps the next person to search will. Also, now it will be highlighted for those who like the udev tag and could get even more good answers. My point is that Jason already _knew_ that this was a systemd/udev thing, he did not retag to make it fit his answer better, his answer was already fine. He retagged because the information in the question showed that the tags were relevant.

Comment: @terdon and more on the topic http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176406/213575, BTW, if networking + arch = udev & systemd is redundant adding such tags since it empirically implies that all networking related questions will have udev and systemd tags

Comment: You can't be serious. This question is not about networking it is about NIC _names_ and _that_ is a systemd/udev thing. Networking is a different issue and not under discussion. As for the latest meta link you gave that says pretty much the same thing I do: "Do re-tag questions to use well-known and popular tags that are appropriate relevant to the question". The other point is not to retag if you're not adding information and, again, this retag _did_ add information so that meta Q supports my position.

Comment: @terdon I think you are not understanding what your logic implies: if I'm writing a program in C you can't tell me that because an answer offers a solution in python I should also use the python tag, if someone offer a perl solution, I should also add perl, if someone has a lisp solution I also should add lisp. That's what your logic implies and what would everyone act. That's is madness in and of itself.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I don't know how many times I need to say this but the retagging was based on information **contained in the question** not the answer. That said, yes, I do actually feel that there are many cases where we _should_ retag based on the answers. If a question was only tagged as `sed` and the accepted answer is an `awk` script, the question should be retagged because if I later look for an `awk` solution for the same problem, I will be able to find it. This is not the case here though since the _question_ is a udev thing since we _know_ that the NIC names depend on that.

Comment: @terdon ok, let me teach you how I evaluate your point of view with my methodology, that maybe you are not taking into account and will shed some lights of why my position about certain topics, but first a bit of history: do you know that the safety belts don't prevent more deaths than what it saves? Crazy, no? Well, result that is like that.

Comment: Before safety belts where default in all cars, drivers were slow and careful when traveling, this is because the benefit of doing so (keep their live) was greater than all the costs (take more time to go from A to B, effort paying attention to the road, etc.). With the introduction of the safety belts the drivers possibility to lose their lives in an accident was practically dismissed. Great! Objective accomplished. Now, lets see the effects on this.

Comment: Since the biggest benefit to driving carefully is no more, and the cost of arriving late to their destiny came pressing, what would drivers do? Start driving faster. I think you may guessed it. Now, what are the effects of driving faster and reckless? The hike on the number of accidents. Now how this affects anyone else who's not driver, like pedestrians?

Comment: Well, if there's a rise in the number of accidents, the probability that they become involved in one increases, and so increase their possibility of losing their lives since they don't have any protection of such events. So, what's the final balance of implementing safety belts? 1) Drivers can drive faster 2) Drivers rarely lose their lives 3) Increasing of the number of accidents 4) Increasing of the expenditures from the state/insurance companies to prevent and mitigate the effect of the accidents 5) More pedestrian lose their lives. Lives saved annually by the seat belts: 500 lives annually

Comment: All this can be corroborated with any source, but there's already a paper written by Hardvard which summarizes it. http://www.law.harvard.edu/programs/olin_center/papers/pdf/341.pdf. Now, what relation has this with the topic at hand? I consider that maybe in your point of view, you are ignoring the hidden costs/effects of the actions you are taking which may be prejudicial in the long term run. Consider carefully that if you motives are to save someone, do not cause harm to another.

Comment: I would like that you use this as template to evaluate your own point of view and answer this questions: What are the benefits? What are the costs? Do the benefits outweighs the costs? What is the collateral effect of this? Which is the best trade off between costs and benefits? Sorry to make this so long, and please take into account that I'm not trying to change your way to rationalize your actions, but you to come to understand mine.

Comment: There is a reason the other answer doesn't mention either tag: the same reason that it doesn't have an upvote nor a green tick... Seriously @Braiam, you need to learn to accept when you are wrong: typing more than the other person doesn't make your argument the better one.

Comment: @jasonwryan nor makes my point less valid either. Have you tried to use my shoes as I did with you and see things how I do?

Comment: @Braiam I could continue to argue, but you are clearly not intent on entertaining other points so I'll save myself the effort.

Comment: @jasonwryan I could say that neither do you. I do entertain and check and validate and reconfirm each point of view with several sources. I would ask to be treated the same way.

Comment: I really don't know how to respond to this wall of comments you posted. I don't see the relevance of that very long story. I have already told you (many, many times) why I consider this particular retagging in particular and adding more tags in general to be a good thing. Let's just leave it at that.

Comment: @terdon let me tell you the relevance: in short, I don't agree with the fundamentals reason behind the action. That's is my claim in and on itself. I was exposing the fundament which I use to tag all and every question, since fundaments are the basic principles which should apply to each and every situation.

Comment: @terdon jasonwryan ok, I may messed up this one and I was wrong, but at very least listen this: please, don't apply the same principle to each and every question. Is a risky gamble where the losses are greater than the possible benefits. Be careful when using this as reason to retag questions. My greater fear is that this sets a precedent that could be calamitous.

Comment: @jasonwryan please, read above comment.